# extjs display confirmation form upon login

Tags: php, extjs3

I am trying to modify someone else's extjs code and I really need some help.

Basically when a username/password is validated the dashboard.js is called which is included in index.php.
Now what I need to do is after the username/password is validated I need another form to popup asking for confirmation number. 
This does not need to be validated(just check for empty string), just entered in the form and  I need to save it in a session.

```
 //index.php
    <script>
            Ext.onReady( function() {

                Web.ip = '<?php print $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>';

                var sessionInfo = Web.getCookieInfo();
                if( sessionInfo ) {
                    Web.Dashboard.init();
                    Web.user = sessionInfo;

                    Web.Dashboard.loadDefault();
                } else {
                    Web.Login.init();
                    Web.Dashboard.init();
                }
            });
        </script>

//dashboard.js
Web.Dashboard = function() {

    var contentPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'fit',
        margins: '0 5 5 0',
        border: true,
        html: ''
    });

    return {

        init: function() {
        ........
        }
    }
}();
```

Here is my success function called inside onsubmit function:

```
success: function( result, request ) {

    try {
        var obj = Ext.decode( result.responseText );
        if( obj.success ) {
            var permissions = obj.USER[0].VALUES;
            var p = {};
            for( var i=0 ; i<permissions.length ; i++ ) {
                p[permissions[i].PERMISSION] = true;
            }


            Web.Dashboard.loadDefault();
        } else {
        //alert ('got here');
            if (obj.ErrorCode == 20410 ) {
                th.changePasswordWindow.show();
                return;
            }
            th.loginPanel.form.reset();
            th.loginWindow.displayInfo( 'Invalid username/password' );
        }
    } catch( ex ) {
        th.loginWindow.el.unmask();
        th.loginPanel.focusUsername();
        th.loginPanel.form.reset();
        th.loginWindow.displayInfo( 'Error: ' + ex );

}
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, edit with a simple ActionSheet, containing another form, it will be a separate form with a single input field - change `textfield.name` and `formpanel.url` so that it matches your serverside.

Once you in your success after a login, create the sheet (or another modal panel popup). Render and show, then send another request to server with `formpanel.getForm().submit()` and you should be good to go.

This sample ActionSheet which has a button handler, adapt that function to your needs (redirecting after success etc)

```
function loginDone() {
...
 if(success) {
 var pincodeSheet = Ext.create("Ext.ActionSheet", {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        cls: 'actionSheetToolbar',
        itemId: 'id_title',
        docked: 'top',
        title: ''
    }, {
        xtype: 'spacer',
        height: 10
    }, {
        xtype: 'formpanel',
        padding: 10,
        url: 'set_session_variable_serverside.asp', // adapt this
        items: [{
            title: 'Please enter PIN',
            cls: 'loginTbarTop',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            cls: 'loginTbarBottom',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'OK',
                ui: 'action',
                handler: function(btn,evt) {
                    // perform any validation here
                    pincodeSheet.down('formpanel').getForm().submit();
                }
            }]
        }, {   /* end docked */
            cls: 'loginFormFieldset',
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            defaults: {
                labelAlign: 'left',
                labelWidth: '35%',
                clearIcon: false
            },
            /* form field declarations */
            items: [{
                tabIndex: 1,
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'session_variable', /// name of input field
                label: 'PIN CODE'
            }] /* end form fields */
        }] /* end form panel items */
    }] /* end sheet items */
 });
 pincodeSheet.render(document.body);


 }

...
}
```

Comment: thanks mschr, I am not sure how to include it inside my success function. see my edit..